# como fazer para abrir a câmera do android e tirar a foto e fazer um upload da foto para o servidor?

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema no a aplicação ela abre a câmera porém não faz o upload aguem pode ver aonde estou errando

segue o codigo

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

   //chamar quando a atividade é a primeira criada
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedIntanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedIntanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Button foto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToFoto);

       Button video = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonToVideo);

       foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                startActivity(intent);

               String arquivo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

               File file = new File(arquivo);

               Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

               intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

           }
       });

       video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

               startActivity(intent);

               String arquivo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis();

               File file = new File(arquivo);

               Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

               intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
           }
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Cara, dê uma olhada nesse artigo. http://www.thiengo.com.br/utilizando-a-camera-do-smartphone-em-sua-app-android

Comment: Não tem nada nesse códiog reference a upload. Acho que está faltando coisa.

Comment: Acho que daria para você separar em duas perguntas.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode abrir a camera automaticamente usando o intent correto, o Android vai abrir a tela da camera sozinha e vc pode tratar a foto do jeito que quiser, salvar localmente, converter em base64, etc. e depois enviar para um WS.

Você precisa das seguintes permissões para que funcione corretamente

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Exemplo para abrir a camera

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/arquivo.jpg");
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE é um código padrão (int normal, pode ser 1, 2, 10, 35, etc) para identificar e tratar o retorno da camera, vc passa essa informação na chamada da activity e depois usa esse mesmo código para validar o retorno da imagem

Depois você precisará tratar o retorno, caso contrário não vai conseguir salvar a imagem nem converter, no exemplo abaixo ele trata o retorno e converte a imagem em base64

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    System.gc(); // garbage colector
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inSampleSize = 3;
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/arquivo.jpg", options);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    boolean validaCompressao = imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream);
                    byte[] fotoBinario = outputStream.toByteArray();

                    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(fotoBinario, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    ibt_foto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap); // ImageButton, seto a foto como imagem do botão

                    boolean isImageTaken = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Picture Not taken",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();e.printStackTrace();
                }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thiago nessa parte do código que vc mandou  ibt_foto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap); o ibt_foto seria o id no botão e o path tem que declarar pois na erro de não pode resolver o simbolo

Comment: Oi, eu esqueci de mudar o "path" ali, mas ele é o caminho+nome do arquivo, no exemplo acima é o `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/arquivo.jpg"` quanto ao ibt_foto, ele é um ImageButton, que depois de tirar a foto eu atualizo a imagem do botão com a foto que foi tirada. Editei o post original e troquei o "path" pelo caminho para não dar erro.